# reverse proxy for nodejs application with https

Tags: nginx

Hi I am hosting a node js application on my raspberry pi. The app itself  is already configured to use https.
I want to setup a reverse proxy so I don't need to directly expose the node js app.

but the following setup gives me a screen with authorization required written on it.

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/alfred.taiman.co.uk.conf

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {

    listen 443;
    server_name alfred.taiman.co.uk;

    access_log            /var/log/nginx/alfred.access.log;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      proxy_pass          https://alfred.local:883;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://alfred.local:883 https://alfred.taiman.co.uk;
    }

}
```

Comment: You've told us nothing about the node.js application - based on the information you provided it is that application requiring authentication. Suggest you review its config, check its logs and try accessing it directly.

Comment: The application doesn't need authentication. When I access it directly i.e. alfred.local:883 I get my webpage.